# Weird PHP behaviour, same field name for Base and Derived classes, cloned instance

Tags: php, inheritance

Sorry for the confused title, I wasn't able to find a better one.
I'm on PHP/5.6.14, I have this code:

```
class Base
{
    private $foo;  <--- NOTE
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->foo = "base foo";
    }
    public final function getFoo()
    {
        return $this->foo;
    }
}

class Derived extends Base
{
    public $foo;  <--- NOTE
    public function __construct($type)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->foo = "derived foo";
        $this->somethingUndefined = "dynamically declared";  <--- NOTE
    }
}

$base = new Base();
var_dump($base->getFoo());
$derived = new Derived(0);
var_dump($derived->getFoo());
$clonedDerived = clone $derived;  <--- NOTE
var_dump($clonedDerived->getFoo());
```

Running the last `getFoo()` gives me:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined property: Derived::$foo in C:..\test.php on
>   line *the line where getFoo() is implemented in the base class*.

If I put this three conditions together I get the notice:

1. same public/private field name
2. having one or more dynamically declared field in the derived class
3. working on a clone of an instance of the derived class

Removing one or more of them makes the notice go away.

What's going on here? `$foo` is not static, and it's not undefined...
I'm using a custom error_handler to turn every E_ALL to an exception and can't really ignore this...

**EDIT**:
This is just an example I wrote to reproduce the issue, real code is much different. I'm NOT trying to expose the private $foo or something. It just happened that Base and Derived were imlemented by different developers that choosed the same name for a field and doing that (along with the other two conditions) caused the Notice. I'm just trying to understand why, since AFAIK it should be perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this to be a bug in PHP, since running that example in PHP7 does not produce this notice. Even more, if you `var_dump($this)` in `getFoo()` definition, it is clearly visible that `"foo":"Base":private` is defined, and `foo` of object `Derived` is defined as well, in both PHP >= 7 and PHP < 7. Please see: https://3v4l.org/Ob9m7

However, I believe that, whatever you are trying to do with this piece of code, you are going about it the wrong way. As [ArtisticPhoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36867399/weird-php-behaviour-same-field-name-for-base-and-derived-classes-cloned-instan/36867607#36867607) already mentioned. I would strongly suggest you reconsider and re-design whatever you are doing. Overriding private members is just not possible as per OOP.

Answer (score 1):

That is the expected behavior, private means this class only.  Therefore the private property `$foo` is not visible to the child class.  Changing it to public is not gonna work, likely there is a warning associated to that that you are not seeing.  What level error reporting to you have on.

Child classes have to keep at least the same visibility of the parent.

At best you could do it private in the child class, but that is not going to give you access to the same `$foo`

Notice or not, the readability of the code is poor, when trying to force a private variable to be something else.  Which foo do you expect to get? And why not just name it something else in the child class if you need `$foo` in the parent as a default, just do an if/then in the child's get method.

Essentially your trying to change the value of `$foo` in the child class when it's private in the parent class.  And then retrieve it from the parent.  As I mentioned at best you wont get the `$foo` you expect and it makes the code confusing.

Comment: This will not trigger a warning/notice/error, since `Base::$foo` is not accessible to Derived class, it can safely declare a new property with the same name.

Comment: I'd have to test it, I was thinking more the lines of abstract classes and interfaces.

Comment: Even though `Base::$foo` is not visible we have this `*the line where getFoo() is implemented in the base class*.`  Which really confuses things.

Comment: I know that private $foo is not visible in the derived class, that's why I assumed it was safe to have another field called $foo there. I'm not trying to override the private $foo. In the real code the derived class is developed by another developer that had no idea $foo already existed in the base class. Still (along with the other two conditions) I found out experimenting that having a public $foo in the Derived class causes the Notice. The code I posted is just a minimal example to reproduce the issue.